# What is the best way to test function that creating a folder with some files?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

My function have to create a folder with some files. What is the best way to write unit test for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some cases:

If files and folder already created
=>You can create a folder with some files in your setup method and delete in your tear-down

If you are giving a wrong path for creation
=>Test for rescue block in your method

If files and folder successfully created
=>You can test it by File.exist? and Dir.exist?(dir_name)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods that can look if a file or a directory exists. The one method is `File.exist?(file_name)` which returns true if the file exists. The other method is `Dir.exist?(dir_name)` which returns true if the directory exists.
Now you can use this methods in your unit test to test if the files and directories exist which your function should create.
For more look her: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html

Comment: Thanks. So, is it ok to create files and folder in the tests? For example, if someone wants execute my tests and he will not have permissions to create files and test will fail. is it ok?

Comment: @nash: If your application would fail in that case, then sure it's ok if the tests fail too.You probably want your tests to write to disk somewhere else than the development and production environments do, just as you have seperate databases for that. On Mac and Linux machines, /tmp is a good place. On Windows, I'm not sure. In any case, remember to clean up and directories/files your tests create.

Comment: Like Marten said, it is important to clean up after the test. When you do that, you can create files and folders as you like in your test.
And if someone will not have permissions to create files or folders, the test will fail, if you test with Dir.exists? or File.exists?